# how can I change this html code to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, dropdown

I'm new to Javascript and our teacher only allows us to use Javascript although most of the examples and answers to my questions are written in html.

I want to make a dropdown button which contains various links.

The example online says:

```
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

so in an attempt to translate this all to Javascript only I wrote

```
var navbar = document.createElement("div");
navbar.className = "navbar";
document.body.append(navbar);

var colorButton = document.createElement("a");
colorButton.innerText = "color";
navbar.append(colorButton);

var genreButton = document.createElement("a");
genreButton.innerText = "genre";
navbar.append(genreButton);

var dropdown = document.createElement("div");
dropdown.className = "dropdown";
dropdown.id = "dropdown";
navbar.append(dropdown);

var dropbtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
dropbtn.className = "dropbtn";
dropbtn.innerHTML = "dropDown";
navbar.appendChild(dropbtn);

var idk = document.createElement("i");
idk.className = "fa fa-caret-down";
dropbtn.append(idk);

var dropDownContent = document.createElement("div");
dropDownContent.className = "dropdown-content";
dropDownContent.id = "myDropdown";
navbar.append(dropDownContent);

var try1 = document.createElement("a");
dropDownContent.append(try1);

var try2 = document.createElement("a");
dropDownContent.append(try2);

var try3 = document.createElement("a");
dropDownContent.append(try3);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

it does show the navbar, the color link, the genre link and the dropdown button. But there is nothing that drops down when I click on it... Could someone explain me how to solve this?
(sorry for the load of code, but maybe there is something else I'm missing and I'm new to this site.)

Comment: you should be using bootstrap classes to achieve it, not implementing custom js for making the dropdown

Comment: Just use the `select` element.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: If the task is to build a **custom dropdown** - I highly doubt you need to mix into that other irrelevant navigation stuff. A dropdown should be a reusable component, not something closely attached to a specific part of the app.

Comment: Also, don't use IDs. On a single page you don't want to end up having multiple IDs just because you used multiple dropdowns.

Comment: You **always** want to use `type="button"` on a BUTTON element, otherwise by default it's type will be `type="submit"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Do you have an example of how such a reusable dropdown component could look is Javascript? Because I've not seen it before.
I also changed BUTTON to button (I had seen that in some other example and I've not used buttons before so I gave it a try), but it's still a button so it doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: @EugenSunic We haven't studied any bootstrap in school yet so I would rather avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This line in function execute when clicking on the button:

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
```

So the class "show" is the key. You need to add some css for class "show" for "myDropdown", so the dropdown will show if it has class "show" and hide if not.

Something like:

```css
#myDropdown {
  display: none;
}
#myDropdown.show {
  display: block;
}
```

You can use js to archive css above with [ElementCSSInlineStyle.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style)

Comment: thank you for answering and the inline style link! I tried changing the css and moving the classname around, but when I click the button it still doesn't show any dropdown links.

Comment: @c0rrm0n In your attemp above, you missed to assign click event to the button, also `try1` `try2` and `try3` does not has any text. Adding them should work.
The DOM structure you created by JS is not correct with html too, but it will not affect the button work.

Answer (score 0):

A Component should be unrelated to other elements or parts of the application.
If you're building a custom Dropdown - stick to it. Insert it where needed.

Here's just an idea / example of a **component** Class to be used like:

```js
const myDropDown = new ComponentDropdown(ElementTarget, {/*options*/});
```

with the help of some utility functions to query or create Elements:

```js
// Utility - DOM Helper functions

const Q = (s, E) => (E||document).querySelector(s); // Query Element
const QA = (s, E) => (E||document).querySelectorAll(s); // Query Elements
const E = (s, a) => Object.assign(document.createElement(s),a||{}); // Create El.
const A = (E, o) => Object.entries(o).forEach(([p, v]) => E.setAttribute(p,v)); // El. attr

/**
 * Component\Dropdown
 * @param {Node} parent - Target node of insertion
 * @param {Object} options - Component options
 */

class ComponentDropdown {
  constructor (parent, options) {
    Object.assign(this, {
      E: {parent},
      isOpen: false,
      text: "Select…",
      items: [],
    }, options);
    this.init();
  }
  
  init() {
    this.E.main = E("div", {className:"dropdown"});
    this.E.button = E("button", {className:"dropdown-button", type:"button", textContent: this.text});
    this.E.content = E("div", {className:"dropdown-content"});
    this.E.items = this.items.reduce((DF, E) => (DF.append(E), DF), new DocumentFragment());
    this.E.main.append(this.E.button, this.E.content);
    this.E.content.append(this.E.items);
    this.E.button.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggle());
    document.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
      if (this.isOpen && !ev.target.closest(".dropdown")) this.toggle();
    });
    this.render();
  }
  
  toggle() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    this.E.main.classList.toggle("is-open", this.isOpen);
  }
  
  render() {
    this.E.parent.append(this.E.main);
  }
  
  destroy() {
    this.E.main.remove();
  }
}

const DD1 = new ComponentDropdown(Q("#DD1"), {
  text: "Other",
  items: [
    E("a", {textContent: "About", href: "#"}),
    E("a", {textContent: "Something", href: "#"}),
    E("a", {textContent: "Projects", href: "#"}),
    E("hr"),
    E("a", {textContent: "Contact", href: "#"}),
  ]
});

// DD1.toggle(); // if you want to render as opened
// DD1.destroy(); // Use to remove dropdown from DOM
```

```css
/* navbar demo */ .navbar { display: flex;} .navbar>* {padding: 0 10px;}

/* Component\Dropdown */

.dropdown {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.dropdown.is-open .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.dropdown-content a{
  display: block;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content hr{
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover{
  box-shadow: inset 3px 0 #0bf;
}

.dropdown-button::after {
  content: "\25be";
  margin-left: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div id="DD1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is an interesting answer, I think you’d benefit from explaining how it works for the OP - and others - to learn. Also, while I love the approach of `\`querySelector${s[0]==="#"?"":"All”}\`` it does come with the caveat of being unable to use a selector such as `#ElementID .elementClassName` to select multiple elements (easily enough to work around by prepending the element’s tag `div#ElementID .elementClassName`).

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica amazing catch about the `"#id .foo"` I usually use two functions for that; it was an unthought quick mashup for this demo purpose only. Worth improving it. I was running a bit out of time with this one so I left details for later. Will review soon.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for answering again! I don't know any query because our teacher didn't talk about it at all. So if anyone has an answer in javascript (and css) only, I'd really really appreciate it.

Comment: @c0rrm0n: this *is* only JavaScript and CSS (admittedly with some HTML to demonstrate the JavaScript and CSS).